# Electrical wave propagation in wire vs space

Tags: wave, propagation

Does it take the same amount of time for the lamps to turn on? Or does it take three times longer for the right lamp to turn on?

[image: Electric wave propagation in wire versus space]

Comment: There is a very short period of time that ***almost no one in EE ever discusses, as this is a physics thing, not a bulk electronic thing*** is needed for charges to set themselves up along the surfaces of conductors throughout a circuit before it starts to operate. These things take place on the order of picoseconds and nanoseconds, before currents settle down. I suppose the timing might be *interesting* to work out in your case. But it is unlikely to be as simple as you imagine.

Comment: @periblepsis you mean, almost no EE, aside from all the high speed digital folks, high-speed analog folks and RF people, the VLSI people, the semiconductor manufacturer people and the EMI people?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yup. That's what I mean. ;) (But also keep in mind that this question is about a DC or low-frequency set up, too. I kind of doubt much need for those folks you mention here.)

Comment: @periblepsis ;) so, yeah, then there's also a few people caring about discharge tube lamps, various vacuum tubes and spark gaps. I think a "you don't usually care about that if you're describing circuits the way you do" would be a tiny bit more appropriate than "nearly no EE works with this": we do that, quite commonly, across a large range of disciplines. EEs is not all low-speed circuits and first semester schematics!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I suppose you are right about that. I also did spend some time with a simpler version of gas discharge (one that didn't include radiation transport or atomic interactions) and it still required 2 spatial and 1 time dimension PDE, coupled with 6-dim ODEs. So I get that, as well. Still, my point kind of still remains as well. I'm not uncomfortable saying it in this context here. But perhaps I should tone it down.

Comment: no need to tone it down, I think it's worthy to see this discussion for OP.

Answer (score 2):

The model that works is that the wire guides the energy, which is transmitted through space. But the energy doesn't follow the surface of the wire: it's flowing throughout the volume of your diagram. A curved wire slows the transmission down, but not as much as you might expect.

A curious fact is that for a fairly wide range of geometric parameters, electromagnetic energy moves along a helical conductor as if it was following the conductor at approximately twice the speed of light. The math here is neither precise nor simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the battery is at first disconnected, but you have a (imagined only) way to connect the wire ends simultaneously to the battery at t=0. You are right. Some electromagnetic wave is created. If you have an AM radio nearby you may hear a click. That's because the wave is not at all in the wire, but in the 3D space around it. And the irregular geometry causes some extremely difficult to calculate amount of radiation, too.

Would it take longer in the rightmost image case before the lamp has high enough voltage to generate light? That's well possible. But that's not caused by the longer route of the radiowave. It's because charging the capacitance of the bigger wire formation takes a longer time.

The route is essentially the same. Note that the wave is in the space, not in the metal and the electric field is needed between the poles of the lamp.

The wave phenomena is in this case extremely complex and only some highly advanced physics simulation program could predict any details of it (assuming the materials and dimensions are fully known). Fortunately practical applications of electricity are possible without knowing the 3D field details. It's enough to guess or calculate right the resulted final voltage and current. In addition human observation ability is so rough and limited that probably it looks like the lamp gets its voltage instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume those are buses for some data, with transmitter and receiver.

In the case of two buses with 1m and 3m of wire the signal will travel at constant speed and will reach receiver at 1m first and it takes the signal 3 times more time to travel 3m, even if the transmitter and receiver are 1cm apart physically.

This is why it is important to match the wiring length of high speed buses, so that signals are at the receiver at the same time and within defined skew in regard to a clock signal.

Comment: That only works for wires close to a ground plane, as on a circuit board. In that case, the electromagnetic energy is confined very close to the wire. But if this is not the case, some of the energy can take shorter routes and thus move faster

Comment: @JohnDoty Why would it need a ground plane? You have twisted pair cables. Unshielded. And you have cables without twisted pairs. All wires have inductance. All wires have capacitance. Therefore all wires are transmission lines. And information still cannot travel even at speed of light, with or without wires.

Comment: Yes, it's the same for twisted pairs, where the field is confined close to the wires. But if the field isn't confined like that, the wave speed may apparently exceed the speed of light along the wire if the wire isn't straight. It's still slower than the speed of light through space: it just doesn't follow every wiggle of the wire.

Comment: @JohnDoty FWIW, group velocity may exceed speed of light for a transmission line too! (For those left incredulous by my comment, the group velocity exceeding c does not imply _data_ or _signals_ can be transmitted faster than c. Special Relativity is not violated. It is a mistake to believe that a signal can always travel at group velocity, which is the velocity of a "beat" created by nearby frequencies.)